# Unexpected character "&" while editing the text using the editor

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, wysiwyg, octobercms

I am using WYSIWYG and CKeditor of Octobercms to edit the text through the admin panel. But, as I edit the text all the spaces present between the HTML tags are replaced with "&" and I get the following error

[image: error]

I looked at the ckeditor.js file to find any function that is being called to parse the HTML but I could not solve it.

Original code:

```
 <div class="container d-flex align-items-center px-4">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ftco-nav" aria-controls="ftco-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="oi oi-menu"></span> Menu
            </button>
            <form action="#" class="searchform order-lg-last">
                <div class="form-group d-flex">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control pl-3" placeholder="Search">
                    <button type="submit" placeholder="" class="form-control search"><span class="ion-ios-search"></span></button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ftco-nav">
                {% component 'menu' %}
```

Code replaced by Ckeditor:

```
<div class="container d-flex align-items-center px-4">Menu
<form action="#">
<div class="form-group d-flex"><input type="text" /></div>
</form>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ftco-nav">{% component &#39;menu&#39; %}
```

Not only "&" but I am getting other characters as well such as "#". I expect the spaces not to be replaced with such characters.

Comment: Did you try using double quotes instead of single quotes?

Comment: That does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your config.js file:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
CKEDITOR.config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
CKEDITOR.config.forcePasteAsPlainText = false;
CKEDITOR.config.basicEntities = true;
CKEDITOR.config.entities = false;
CKEDITOR.config.entities_latin = false;
CKEDITOR.config.entities_greek = false;
CKEDITOR.config.entities_processNumerical = false;
CKEDITOR.config.fillEmptyBlocks = function (element) {
    return true;
};
CKEDITOR.config.autoParagraph = false;
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.span = 0;
CKEDITOR.dtd.a.div = 1;
CKEDITOR.dtd.a.p = 1;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you are using a WYSIWYG plugin on CMS pages?

This issue is caused by the ckeditor wanting to parse an apostrophe as `&#39;`. It doesn't work because `{% component 'menu' %} is a twig function and because the ckeditor is changing it to`'` it won't work.

I forget there might be way to turn off strict parsing in the settings. Depends on what plugin you are using.

Try working with [Static Pages instead](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-pages).

If you are using this plugin you can turn it off. Install and use [Static Pages instead](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-pages)

[image]

Comment: I am using ckeditor. As I am new with octobecms can you guide me there?  I am not able to solve this issue and could not find any solution online

Comment: There is no solution turn off CKEditor for CMS Pages. Then install static pages instead.

Comment: @user9053914 How did you solve it? post your answer and mark as correct.